# How to change the "modified date" in Outlook 2010

Tags: windows, outlook, ms-office, mapi

The following actions will change the message's modified date/time:

- Forwarding
- Replying
- Replying to All
- Editing and Saving
- Moving or Copying

Source (I know its an old one, but I think its up to date): http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=197981

We need to change the conditions for this date, so that for example the date only changes when the category of the mail will be changed.

My question: Is this possible? Which language need to be used? MAPI?

Answer (score 0):

Created and last modified dates are calculated by the store provider and cannot be modified.
If you are using the PST provider, you can roll back the system clock before making a change.